# bbappend file for replacing a file

Tags: yocto, intel-edison

I created a new layer in yocto: meta-abc, a recipe: abc-efg_0.1.bb and an .bbapend: abc-efg_01.bbapend file.
With the bbappend file I want to overwrite a file from intel-edison board.
More exactly, the wpa_supplicant.conf from /etc/wpa_supplicant/.
This wpa_supplicant.conf is already created from another layer (meta-intel-edison-distro).
I can write my file in /etc/ so my recipe and my bbappend file are working.
I can bitbake my recipe, but when I try to creat the image I receive the message:

" * check_data_file_clashes: Package abc-efg wants to install file /home/atr-int/Desktop/Yocto/yocto-edison/build_edison/tmp/work/edison-poky-linux/edison-image/1.0-r0/rootfs/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
    But that file is already provided by package  * wpa-supplicant
 * opkg_install_cmd: Cannot install package abc-etc.
"
Here is my bbappend file content:

```
FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/${PN}:"

SRC_URI += "file://wpa_supplicant.conf"

do_install_append() {
install -d ${D}${sysconfdir}/wpa_supplicant
install -m 0755 ${WORKDIR}/wpa_supplicant.conf 
    ${D}${sysconfdir}/wpa_supplicant
}
```

Can anyone give my any tip ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You shouldn't rewrite the `wpa_supplicant.conf` from another recipe, as the files will clash.

Instead, rename your `abc-efg_01.bbapend` to `wpa-supplicant_%.bbappend`, and it should work.

If for some reason you need to have `wpa_supplicant.conf` in `abc-efg`, you need to add a `wpa-supplicant_%.bbappend` in which you'll need to remove `wpa_supplicant.conf`.

Comment: I need to replace the wpa_supplicant.conf with my own configuration (what i want to do is connect my intel-edison to WiFi automatically) . That's why I really need to replace the one that is already generating from the layer 'meta-intel-edison' with the one I have  created.

Comment: Yes, you replace the wpa_supplicant.conf file using a bbappend in your own layer. Do not create an extra recipe, unless you have some other requirements.

Comment: Thank you. I did that and now my file is overwite in the right place. :)

Comment: Do you think you can help me with some other problem I have?

Comment: I'm trying to make a link to the wpa_supplicant.service. My version is:                                  do_install_append() { ln -s '$/lib/systemd/system/wpa_supplicant.service' '${D}${sysconfdir}/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/wpa_supplicant.service' }  After I bitbake the .bbappend and the image and flash  it on my board there is no link in /etc/.../system/multi-user.target.wants for 'wpa_supplicant.service'. Do you have any idea what I can do more? Thank you.

Comment: Well, you want to enable `wpa_supplicant.service`? Then the easiest way would be to add `SYSTEMD_AUTO_ENABLE = "ensable"` to your  `.bbappend`. As you can see in the original recipe, it's disabled per default.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not working. I made the bbapend with the line that you gave you me and removed the link, and also this both of them, but the wpa_supplicant.service is not starting.                                                                   FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/files:"
SYSTEMD_AUTO_ENABLE = "ensable"

Comment: do_install_append() {
    if ${@base_contains('DISTRO_FEATURES','systemd','true','false',d)}; then
        ln -sf '$/lib/systemd/system/wpa_supplicant.service' '${D}${sysconfdir}/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/wpa_supplicant.service'
    fi
}                                                                                                                         Is this right? Or should i do something more?

Comment: Did you spell `enable` correctly? As this is how many other recipes are working...
And for you manual linking why do you have `$/lib/systemd`? You should preferably use `${systemd_system_unitdir}` instead of most directories in your path.

Comment: Thank you very much for all the help you gave me. I did the changes.                 FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/files:"
SYSTEMD_AUTO_ENABLE = "enable"

do_install_append() {
    if ${@base_contains('DISTRO_FEATURES','systemd','true','false',d)}; then
        ln -sf '${systemd_system_unitdir}/wpa_supplicant.service' '${D}${sysconfdir}/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/wpa_supplicant.service'
    fi
}

Comment: My bbappend file looks now like this. It's still not working. If you have any other idea it would be so nice...

Comment: You shouldn't need your `do_install_append`. Using ` SYSTEMD_AUTO_ENABLE = "enable"` should be enough. Just adding that one to my own bbappend, gave me `/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/wpa_supplicant.service`. Well, to be honest, I also had `SYSTEMD_SERVICE_${PN} = "wpa_supplicant.service"`.

Comment: I was having a file in /files. I deleted it and  now it's working. Thank you very much. Have a very nice day!

Answer (score 1):

Install extra files for p910nd with bbappend file:

layout of p910nd directory

```
.
├── files
│   ├── p910nd.conf
│   └── p910nd.init
└── p910nd_0.97.bbappend
```

Content of the bbappend file

```
SUMMARY = "install init script"
FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/files:"
SRC_URI += "file://p910nd.init"
SRC_URI += "file://p910nd.conf"

RDEPENDS_${PN} += "bash"

do_install_append() {
         install -D -m 0644 ${WORKDIR}/p910nd.conf ${D}${sysconfdir}/default/p910nd
         install -D -m 0755 ${WORKDIR}/p910nd.init ${D}/etc/init.d/p910nd
}
```

In my test, do_install_append will also overwrite the file if the it is already installed in the destination.